# Install package Google Analytic

Tags: google-analytics

I can not install the package `composer require spatie/laravel-analytics` as [the link here](https://github.com/freekmurze/laravel-analytics)
I'm using laravel 4.2

[Here's the screenshot](http://prntscr.com/6wqalp)

Comment: Can you provide more details please? What have you tried? What error messages are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

This error on screenshot means that one of composer.json dependencies is broken and has incorrect version.

It can be either in your own composer.json or in one of the packages that you are trying to install. Search for ^1.2.2 in your source to identify which package is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I got the correct answer, I use `php composer.phar self-update` before running that code, then it works well